# Using Flat-Flex for CAN connection

Tags: connector, cables, can, ribbon-cable, flexible

I am currently developing a robot with multiple modules that have to be connected using CAN (at 5V or 3.3V). The robot has 2 strong DC motors (with spikes over 100A) and also operates close to powerful magnetic fields.

In order to have a compact design I am considering to use flat-flex for the connections, but I am concerned about not using twisted pairs. Is it critical to have twisted pairs?

Do you have any suggestions for a cable type that would be compact and also suit such an application?

Comment: `Is it critical to have twisted pairs?` No. It's not required to use twisted pairs for CANBus. Actually, it's designed to be used with standard cables *(i.e. neither shielded cables nor twisted pairs)*. If very low EMI is required then you should use twisted pairs.

Comment: How long are the wires? Which kind of flat flex? What baudrate? Any stubs?

Comment: maximum 20 cm. I haven`t decided on the type of flat flex and I`m not sure about the baud rate..

Comment: At 20cm the wire type isn't going to matter much, even if it's a stub. Long as it can handle the current - I'd design for >100mA. Other than that, you should focus on other EMC aspects instead: filters and TVS etc.